# Unable to get value from JSON after mySQL

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express

```
var sender_username = req.session.user_id;
var recipient_username = req.body.recipient_username; 
var content = req.body.content; 

var sql = ' SELECT sender_username, recipient_username, COUNT(recipient_username) as count FROM message WHERE sender_username = "'+sender_username+'" AND recipient_username = "'+recipient_username+'" GROUP BY sender_username LIMIT 1 ';
var message_no = 0;
var data;

connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        data = result; 
        // res.send(data); < - this works
        // res.send(result); <- this works
        // res.send(result.count); <- undefined
    }
});

res.send(data); // undefined (can't seem to save to variable after connection.query())
```

The `res.send(result);` seems to work. It gives:

```
[{"sender_username":"sender","recipient_username":"recipient","count":2}]
```

I am just trying to get the value for `count` and save that to a variable, but things like `result.count` are returning undefined for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the JSON is an array, so you should access it like the following

```
res.send(result[0].count);
```

Comment: I needed a toString(). :P res.send((result[0].count).toString()) Thanks!